# Height of Everest from base to top

Tags: geology, mountains

It's relatively well known that Everest is the *highest* mountain above sea level, and that Mauna Kea in Hawaii is the *tallest* mountain from base to top.

But how tall is Everest from base to top? Or to put it another way, how high is Everest's base?

Comment: A difference between the two examples that you mention is that Mauna Kea stands pretty much alone - it's a single mountain from seabed to peak. It's much harder to define where the "base" of Everest is.

Comment: Hmm... this is a relatively simple question. Shouldn't Google be the place to go for this? Please don't ask questions just because you can, try to google it first. If you can't find a clear cut answer, then come back here! Just my thoughts...

Comment: Much of Mauna Kea is underwater however. The tallest mountain from base to peak above the sea is Mt McKinley (Denali) in Alaska.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The height of Everest above its base depends on where one considers its base to be - and this depends on which side of the mountain one looks.

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_Everest),

> reasonable base elevations for Everest range from 4,200 m (13,800 ft)
>   on the south side to 5,200 m (17,100 ft) on the Tibetan Plateau,
>   yielding a height above base in the range of 3,650 to 4,650 m (11,980
>   to 15,260 ft).

Comment: yeah defining the base is the hard part, technically much of the mountain is below ground, reminiscent of a iceberg.

Answer (score 1):

The 1954 recorded height of 8,848 m remains the accepted figure for height. As for the elevation of Everest's base, it is 5,380 m (at 17,600 ft).

Comment: Oh, interesting. How is the base defined?

Comment: According to South Base Camp in Nepal, since North Base Camp in China has its access restricted.

Comment: I don't think the elevation of a base camp is the same as the elevation of the base of a mountain - they are the same word, but with different meanings.

Comment: Having said, that, it appears to be in the right ballpark. From Wikipedia, "reasonable base elevations for Everest range from 4,200 m (13,800 ft) on the south side to 5,200 m (17,100 ft) on the Tibetan Plateau"